# How to use a remote node on a very bandwitdh restricted connection?

Tags: linux, bandwidth, vps

I set up a remote node for Monero using SSH tunneling, it works great.

The problem is that it's using quite a bit of bandwidth. I assumed all bandwidth intensive operations were done in the remote node, but my local monero-wallet-cli downloaded hundreds of MBs in a few minutes.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: important clarification. I don't want to restrict the bandwidth used by Monero at any given point of time. Like setting it to use a max of 16 KB for download and upload. I want it to download and upload as little data as possible over a long period of time.

Answer (score 3):

If you update to the coming release, and if the remote node you're using is using a recent daemon (the one that'll come with that release), the bandwidth will be much less when refreshing the wallet.

For current blocks (ie, after the ringct change), the bandwidth should be less than 5% what it was.